# ¿Cómo compilar python a un standalone.exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He intentado compilar un código de python que funciona perfectamente usando estos comandos.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install pyinstaller

pyinstaller -F my_app.py
```

Y se me ha creado un ejecutable (my_app.exe) bastante grande además (casí 6mb).

La cuestión es que cuando lo voy a ejecutar me da un error de dependencias

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_app.py", line 10, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fulanito'
```

Me pregunto si hay alguna otra forma de compilarlo para que se haga un ejecutable totalmente independiente (Standalone) y que corra de forma nativa sin necesidad de ser interpretado.

Comment: Python es un lenguaje interpretado. Para ejecutarlo siempre debes tener Python instalado. Pyinstaller  y varios otros, lo que hacen es "congelar" tu script, empaquetandolo con un interprete python y todas la librerías que necesitas. Hay un intento de generar código de maquina (compilar) código python, que se llama nuitka pero esta bastante verde. Por otro lado el error que estás mostrando es por la falta del módulo `fulanito.py`, debería compartir el código y la estructura de tus carpetas para poder entender el problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder!! Vaya, que desilusión lo de que no se pueda hacer!! :-(  el código está en este repositório, forma parte del API de Google. Aquí te dejo el enlace. https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload